# Twigbridge and PHP7

Tags: php, laravel-5, twig, composer-php

I was playing around with my new PHP7 server and it turns out that twigbridge doens't play nice (or doesn't play at all).

```
InvalidArgumentException in ServiceProvider.php line 236:
Cannot instantiate Twig extension 'TwigBridge\Extension\Laravel\String': Class TwigBridge\Extension\Laravel\String does not exist
```

I've tried this on multiple 5.x versions and it's fine but just not in 7. Is it really just not compatible or can this be remedied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 7, `String` [cannot be used as class, interface, or trait name](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php), because it would be ambiguous with scalar typehinting for strings.

You will need `TwigBridge` >= v0.8.2, which includes a [fix for this](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge/commit/2d57cd6b7b7e6cd4a1ed9246d4bf1087785e5fc4) (by renaming their `String` class to `Str`).

Comment: Worked! Just change it to `0.9.1` and update your config to use the extension `TwigBridge\Extension\Laravel\Str` instead of `TwigBridge\Extension\Laravel\String`.